# How to use setInterval with random number of milliseconds each time?

Tags: javascript, random, setinterval

The function `showRandom` is executed every 1000 milliseconds but i want it to be executed every `random` milliseconds..  is there any solution for this ? Thank you!

```
var random = 1000;
setInterval(function() {random = randomizator(60000,200000);} ,1000);
setInterval(function() {showRandom(random);}, random);
function randomizator(a,b)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*b) + a;
}
function showRandom(random)
{
    $('#test').text(random);
}
```

**DEMO: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smotru/pLTrJ/)**

Comment: Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: @FelixKling: I've made my answer a CW, since it's really your answer, I just put it where the OP can accept it. :-) (I know you don't care, in fact I'm sure no one cares but me. But it felt wrong. And besides, two makes a community. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: You didn't have to, but I appreciate the good intention :) (yay, community!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Felix said it: If you want to change the interval every time, use `setTimeout` instead. Simplified example as I'm having trouble following exactly what you want your original code to do:

```
doTheRandom();
function doTheRandom() {
    random = randomizator(60000,200000);
    // Up to 1 second
    setTimeout(doTheRandom, randomizator(1000, 2000)); // 1-2 seconds
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I need the random to be global to use later.

Comment: @smotru: The above continues using the global. (There's no `var` in front of `random`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
    setInterval(function() {
//your code to be executed every random miliseconds
} ,random_interval());


var random_interval=function(){
return Math.random()*1000;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. This chooses a random interval once and uses that same interval each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random interval you could use setTimeout instead. Heres an example to give you an idea (not tested could contain errors):

```
function setRandomInterval(){
//Add your code here
setTimeout(function(){
  setRandomInterval();
}, Math.random()*1000);
```

}

The problem with setInterval is, that once you've setted it the interval is fixed. You could stop the interval and start a new one but setTimeout will be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the implementation of `setInterval(fn,PERIOD)` using `setTimeout` is :

```
     setTimeout(fn,iteration*PERIOD)  // iteration ∈ [1,2,3...,n]
```

So ,what you need is to use `setTimeout` , with randomizing `iteration*PERIOD`

Comment: Thanks for your input, since this is a 3yrs old post, I don't even remember what I used this for. But since we are back to this topic, please tell me how iteration * PERIOD would be random?